# Can I move the OS X that was preinstalled on my MacBook pro to a VM running on the MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, unix, software, virtualbox, license

I would like to run linux as the primary operating system on my MacBook Pro to replace the OS X that was pre-installed with the MacBook.

I would then like to run OS X inside a virtualbox guest running on the MacBook.

1. Is this configuration legal from a licensing perspective?
2. My mac book was pre-installed and there wasn't an installation CD in the box.  How can I get the OS X installation image for installing into Virtualbox?

UPDATE:
I have NOT purchased a copy of OS X, and I do not wish to purchase one either :)

Comment: Why not use bootcamp to install linux and set that as your startupdrive? On newer macbooks there aren't any installation discs required, because they normally have a recovery partition.

Comment: I will probably need to regularly switch between Linux and OS X.   It looks like bootcamp is a dualboot mechanism which will make switching between OS's a pain?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to download the Yosemite installer (or another OSX version if your "purchased" it earlier) and try if you can install a virtual machine with it. You could also visit this link (it is for parallels, but maybe it will also work with virtual box): http://kb.parallels.com/en/118806

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, I've updated the question to reflect that purchasing a copy of OS X is not something I want to do.

Comment: By purchasing I mean that an os x version is linked to your apple id. OSX Maverics and OSX Yosemite are both free to download fron the appstore.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see the yosemite installer in the AppStore. Follow the instructions [here](http://www.macworld.com/article/2367748/how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-10-10-yosemite-install-drive.html) to create a bootable disk for yosemite (os x 10.10). Similar instructions can be found for mavericks or older versions with a simple google search.

Then format the harddrive and install linux.

Then download vmware or your preferred vm client and set up the vm using your bootable disk.